# Dell 2950 Disk Partition Format System Install

Tags: partition, format

Have three 2950 Servers. Got them here and there. Fixed all the little problems. All are posting.  Have new SAS drives.  I need to format and partition them.

How do you get raw SAS drives formatted and partitioned.  Let me add, they are 3TB so need one a 2G part and a 1G ??  Manual says will only take 2G drive.  Don't want to get all elaborate and upgrade to H700.  If these drives won't work, I just buy some smaller ones.

Still, can't figure out how to format without install and can't install w/o format.

Comment: `Still, can't figure out how to format without install and can't install w/o format` sorry but this is just wrong. Every OS can format disks during install. You usually don't format disks beforehand. If you can't format disks during the installation it's because you are missing drivers for the controller. Even if you manage to format them beforehand, you will still be unable to use them without the necessary drivers.

Answer (score 2):

The controller in 2950 is not capable of addressing more than 2TB on a HDD. Any drive larger than 2TB will either not be recognized or will be detected as a 2TB HDD.